# Python: Remove all types of bullet points from a string

Tags: python, python-re

As the question states..
My requirement is to remove all types of bullet points ("•","●"....).

Strange thing is that I am opening a file from Python Code using open(FilePath,encoding="utf8") and storing all the data in a variable and the bullet points are coming out as a string instead of /u____.

Now I want to replace all those Bullet points via Regex or any logic.

Can please someone provide me something??

Comment: A literal unicode escape sequence is *completely equivalent* to its corresponding symbol. For example, the literals ``"\u0041"`` and ``"A"`` represent exactly the same string. Please [edit] your question to clarify whether you are dealing with unicode symbols, the equivalent escape sequence, or textual representations of escape sequences (e.g. ``"\\u0041"`` for the previous example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

It never came to my mind that it's not about removing/replacing the bullet points. But, it was all about considering text other than that. It sounds same but programmatically different.

Solution: I used re.

```
My_All_File_Text_With_Bullets = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', ' ', My_All_File_Text_With_Bullets)
```

And this works like a charm.

Comment: Heads up that this will work only for an extremely narrow subset of "text". Many non-English languages, and even significant parts of English, use more letters than ASCII alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use STRING.replace(), just like this:

```
my_string = my_string.replace('•', '')
```

this would replace the bullet point with nothing.

Comment: dont know why but the bullet point is not shown in the answer so here is the correct verion ,my_string = my_string.replace(':', '')

Comment: It's a feasible solution for if and only if the string has 1 type of bullet point. However, it won't work for all types. Writing out replace statements for all is a lengthy path one shouldn't use. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Note that ``str.translate`` is more appropriate to remove *multiple* different symbols.